# Populating nested dictionary from database query

Tags: python, dictionary

I have data in a database that look like this (simplified)

```
colA, colB, colC
'a',   1,   'abc'
'a',   2,   'def'
'b',   1,   'ghi'
'b',   2,   'jkl'
```

My aim is to build a nested dictionary from that table, that looks like this:

```
dict = {a: {1: 'abc'}, {2: 'def'},
        b: {1: 'ghi'}, {2: 'jkl'}}
```

I have few more nested levels in my real case.
Being a database query, I imagine I can do a 'for' loop line by line

Any suggestion to an elegant/efficient way to populate a dictionary this way?

Comment: I suggest you use pandas, Hierarchical indexing can do what you want. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can feed the results of a `cursor.fetchall()` to this function. It handles any number of columns >= 2.

```
def nest(rows):
    root = {}
    for row in rows:
        d = root
        for item in row[:-2]:
            d = d.setdefault(item, {})
        d[row[-2]] = row[-1]
    return root
```

---

Another approach to create arbitrarily deep nested dictionaries is this:

```
import collections

def nesteddict():
    return collections.defaultdict(nesteddict)

nd = nesteddict()
for a, b, c in rows:
    nd[a][b] = c
```

Comment: or `from collections import defaultdict` :)